# fiware-orion "code" : "400", "details" : "invalid payload: unknown fields"

Tags: fiware-orion

I've created an Orion instance based on orion-psb-image-R4.2 instance in FIWARE Lab, just updated (orion, pep, cygnus) after setting it. It is listening on internet and I have verified connevity and so.

I tried to create a simple instance with this query:

```
POST http:x.y.w.z:1026/v1/contextEntities/
```

Headers:
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

Body:

```
{
   "id": "Sala1",
   "type": "Sala",
   "Attributes": [
      {
         "name": "temperatura",
         "type": "float",
         "value": "20"
      },
      {
         "name": "humedad",
         "type": "float",
         "value": "80"
      }
   ]
}
```

The answer received from the Web server is:
200, OK
Date: Fri, 05 Feb 2016 10:34:51 GMT
Content-Length: 132
Content-Type: application/json

But the answer from ORION is:

```
{
   "errorCode": {
      "code": "400",
      "reasonPhrase": "Bad Request",
      "details": "invalid payload: unknown fields"
   }
}
```

Any idea on what I'm missing?.

Thanks & Regards.

**EDIT**: Sorry... that's something I already fixed.  Somehow I copied it wrongly.
The previous error was "json syntax error".
That's fixed.
The error I reported remains after writing "attributes" with lower case "a".
Any other idea?

```
POST: HTTP://x.y.w.z:1026/v1/contextEntities/

HEADERS
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

BODY
{
"id": "Sala1",
"type": "Sala",
"attributes": [
 { 
   "name": "temperature",
   "type": "float",
   "value": "20" 
 },
 { 
   "name": "humidity",
   "type": "float",
   "value": "80" 
 }
]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Daniel, you need to edit your original question, not use the "Answer" to have a discussion. Discussions in StackOverflow are carried on in Comments.

Comment: As you can see in this execution session https://gist.github.com/fgalan/f97da64f7bb65ecc1da0 I'm using your exact payload with the curl command and everything seems to be ok. Could you do the same *exact* test (I mean, the same test.sh file, just changing localhost by the actual IP of the CB in your case) and answer to this comment with the result, please?

Comment: Ok. It works now. Once I executed the POST query IN the server itself. I thought I could create the instance remotely by using a REST client or using curl. Now that it is created I can change the values (using POST) and getting  the values using (GET) remotely. Thanks for your support & help.

Answer (score 0):

Orion API is case sensitive. Thus, probably the problem is that your payload uses `Attributes` instead of `attributes` (i.e. lower-case `a`).